# IE(8 in 7-compat mode) uses "@media print" rule - on the screen

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have this rule which says "use this CSS rule ONLY FOR PRINTING.

```
@media print {
    .yui-dt-bd {
        width: 920px !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        page-break-before: avoid !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
        position: static !important;
    }
}
```

The link-to-CSS-file with media-specification shows the same result, by the way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

However, what do I see when I debug my page with the IE8 dev. tool (F12)? It applies those rules to the page (media=screen)!

I looked long and hard but found nothing on the web, only the "IE **ignores** this or that", **which is the opposite of MY problem**.

IE dev. tool window says: "Browser Mode: IE7, Document Mode: IE7 Standards". I don't use any @import statement anywhere (this was an issue in some other IE CSS questions I found so I mention it). All 5 rules (above) are applied (on the screen media).

EDIT: Updated and follow-up question merged into this one.

EDIT: **This is not a CSS3 media query**, which is of course not supported by IE8 and below. This is media dependent CSS. I did not find anything conclusive, but it seems that THIS SHOULD work, as long as I don't use CSS3 media query features, which seem not to include THIS example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 and below [do not](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) support media queries, so your issue might be related to an unclosed tag  or conditional comment somewhere in your css or page. Run a [CSS linter](http://csslint.net/) or [validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) your css to see if you catch any tags that might need closing.

Comment: Ah yes indeed. I'm only debugging old code, and I checked compatibility of course - but ended up looking at media queries in the HTML link tag which includes CSS files. So strange that no one ever complained, the app using this has been in use for years... :)

Comment: I just posted a follow-up Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160453/ie-applies-link-stylesheet-media-print-on-the-screen

Comment: There is no media query in use here. IE has great support for CSS2 media types whether in `<link media="">` or in `@media` blocks.

Comment: Okay... so why doesn't it work, or maybe I should say why DOES it work (while I don't want it to, at least not on the screen)?

Comment: @Mörre beyond this point we are only guessing. Can you post your stylesheet or test page to take a look?

Comment: Q rectracted for now, because: I created a very simple one-page test case with a "@media print" rule. The IE dev. tools indeed show that that rule is applied, but what I can actually see on screen says otherwise. HOWEVER, for me the case is not yet closed, because in my (huge, inherited) app the print-rule also seems to be actually applied on screen, proof: when I disable it (in the dev. tools window) the original (non-print) rule takes over again. I hate IE :)

Comment: @Mörre bizarre. I can't see why that would happen and would like to find out, so when you have more information please post back. I've had issues like this before but they were due to unclosed tags in my CSS. Also, make sure that you're conforming to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

Comment: CSS Lint has some warnings (which are harmless, I checked them) but no errors (even though the concatenated file is pretty big). I'll keep looking. I discovered worse (unrelated): when I hide a (YUI2) DataTable with visibility:hidden and remove the the class doing this once the various table and column dimensions have been calculated, IE does not display the "border:" lines (reversing this innocent visibility change gets them back)!!! Did I already say that I HATE!!!!! IE :) ;(

Comment: I noticed only now (so much later) that your link points to CSS3 (three!!!) media QUERIES. However, my code is simple media dependent CSS, which has been around much longer - I found references to CSS examples using this option with browsers as far back as IE5 (five!).
Anyway, I no longer have that issue, or no one has complained recently, not sure what or even IF I changed anything, and if so, what it was... so sorry :(